# jQuery .animate somehow not reacting (for a WP site)

Tags: jquery

This is a bit embarrassing and frustrating in one. What I am trying to do is animate the width and the position of divs for a site. I have made a test and it works fine there:

http://romanaltenburg.com/temp/test.php

Hoever, for the real website, the .animate does nothing at all. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        pWidth = $("#all_staff").width();
        pLeft = $("#all_staff").position();
        pLeft = pLeft.left;
        pCount = $("#[id^=member_]").size();
        pPercent = 100/pCount;
        zIndex = 0;
        colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099","#9624CF","#CCCCCC"];

        //$("#[id^=member_]").addClass("staff_member");
        $("#[id^=member_]").css("width", pWidth/pCount);
        $("#[id^=member_]").css("z-index", zIndex);

        for (i=1;i<=pCount;i++){
            $("#member_"+i).css("left", (pWidth/pCount)*(i-1)+pLeft+"px");
            $("#member_"+i).css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
        }

        $("#[id^=member_]")
            .hover(function() {
                $(this).animate({ left: 20 }, 'fast');
            }, function() {
                $(this).animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
        });

});
```

The REALLY frustrating part is that any other function works fine for those divs. So if I write this here

```
$("#[id^=member_]")
  .hover(function() {
      $(this).css("left", "20px");
  }, function() {
      $(this).css("left", "0px");
});
```

the divs jump where I tell them to. Why? WHY? WHYYYYYYYYYYY? :) Don't get it, please help me out. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the member_ elements aren't available in the DOM at this point. I would try using the follwing instead of hover

`live` for JQuery before 1.7
and 
`on` for JQuery after

which will bind the elements if they appear in the DOM afterwards

Comment: I was thinking that too, but then why would I be able to change the CSS on hover and not add the animate? Guess that's handles in a different way then?

Just tried your suggested solution though. Funny thing is it skips the mouseOver and goes straigh to mouseOut. And still no animating.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot without a link to the real web site, but I would do this, in order:

- Turn on console (in Chrome, or Firebug in FF), see what's breaking it on the live site
- Make sure you're loading jquery, etc in the right order before your js file

Also, you might want to try notating your selector differently, since it's a "string" you're passing to jQuery:

```
$('#[id^="value"]')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh yes, forgot the link to the site... sorry
http://www.stories.ch/website_new/about/

A problem I could think of is that I have the animation code below the <head> for now. I wanted to test it first before making it clean. Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

Having the animate below the head should be fine.  Have you tried writing it as such:

```
$("#[id^=member_]")
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ left: '+=20px' }, 'fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({ left: '-=20px' }, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: That's a good idea, didn't know that works too. Unfortunately, it does not work in my case. I'm starting to think jQuery is not initialized properly. Thanks a lot for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what I did, but suddenly it seems to be working now. It could be that I have values in quotes now, like Bear Alexander has it. So, thanks for that!!!

Comment: If some answer was helpful to you, don't forget to accept/upvote [http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)